# how to prevent ajax returned json encoded result to appear in console?

Tags: jquery, json, console, autosuggest

I'm trying to build a autosuggeset feature in my website. The users enter something in the text field, then ajax send that data to php side, ran a query in database, and return the result array back to the page. The problem is that I don't want the browser console to shows what's being returned.

Here are my basic structures:

main.php:

```
<input type="text" id="title" />
<div id="suggest_box" style="display:none"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$("input#title").keyup(function(){

  var url = "suggest.php";
  var data = $(this).val();

  $.post (url, data)
  .success (function(result){
    var jsonObj    = $.parseJSON( result );

    var suggestObj   = jsonObj.title_list;

  });

});
```

suggest.php

```
// returning the result array

$json = new stdClass();
$json->title_list = $result;

echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I have checked the autosuggest feature in other popular websites, they didn't show anything in the console, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the data is sent to the browser it can be inspected in the console. You can't prevent that

Comment: So how can I return values from ajax that can't be inspected like the other autosuggest?

Comment: no idea what you are really referring to. Show examples. My guess is you have some console.log's in your code

Comment: something like the search in http://www.puzzledragonx.com. When I enter a name or a number, it will search the database and return a autosuggest list, but that list wouldn't be showing up in the console. How can I do something similar to this?

Comment: can see their data in console, look at get request to `dictionary.txt`. They just load the whole file rigth when page loads which is fine if you aren't searching through many thousands of rows